# Are MSIL opcodes atomic?

Tags: .net, multithreading, atomic, cil

I was playing a bit with the MSIL decompiler - ILDASM and I tried to decompile a simple .NET method.

The opcodes looked somehow like this:

```
.method private hidebysig static int32  Add(int32 a,
                                            int32 b) cil managed
{
  // Code size       18 (0x12)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] int32 c,
           [1] int32 d,
           [2] int32 CS$1$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0003:  add
  IL_0004:  stloc.0
  IL_0005:  ldarg.1
  IL_0006:  ldc.i4.s   10
  IL_0008:  add
  IL_0009:  stloc.1
  IL_000a:  ldloc.0
  IL_000b:  ldloc.1
  IL_000c:  add
  IL_000d:  stloc.2
  IL_000e:  br.s       IL_0010
  IL_0010:  ldloc.2
  IL_0011:  ret
}
```

What I'm wondering is - are these opcodes atomic? i.e In a preemptive scheduling kernel, is it possible for a single opcode to be preempted before it finishes execution? The opcode in here could be easily mapped to asm instructions pretty much 1:1, as they have separate opcodes for loads, stores, add, etc.

But what in case of a more complex opcodes? like "call", when the operand is a method-reference token that should first be followed to resolve the method and then called? is that atomic too?

Comment: It depends on the processor...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, not all opcodes are atomic. For example, if you use `stloc` or `ldloc` for value types which are larger than the native pointer size, that's not guaranteed to be atomic.

Section 12.6.6 of ECMA 335 guarantees this much:

> A conforming CLI shall guarantee that read and write access to properly aligned memory locations no larger than the native word size (the size of type native int) is atomic (see §12.6.2) when all the write accesses to a location are the same size. Atomic writes shall alter no bits other than those written.

... but then there's a note:

> [Note: There is no guaranteed atomic access to 8-byte data when the size of a native int is 32 bits even though some implementations might perform atomic operations when the data is aligned on an 8-byte boundary. end note]

So that means any op code storing or reading an `Int64` isn't guaranteed to be atomic on x86, for example...

Comment: WOW! That is a surprising eye-opener. This means that if you have two threads that store values to a variable of type "long" in a scope visible to both of them, you might expect that value to have a value not equal to any of the stores. right?

eg. thread1 { val = 1 }, thread2 { val = 4294967296}, the resulting value might be 4294967297? Because these values touch two different 32-bitsets? And the only way to have a guarantee that either of these two values is going to be stored is using Interlocked.* ?

Comment: Yes. Volatile does not help either. (It helps with very litte)

Comment: @KarimA.: Absolutely. Sharing state between multiple threads without any locking is tricky... try to avoid needing to do so.

Comment: @John, but in case of ints (32 bit integers) I have the guarantee that the stored value in the global variable would be one of the two. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @KarimAgha You can guarantee **atomic 64-bit fetch and store** in *both* 32- and 64-bit modes by *always* using the `Interlocked.*` instructions to read/write the affected memory locations. For .NET in 32-bit mode, this is the only way to obtain the correctness guarantee required for 64-bit lock-free operation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think atomicity is defined on IL instructions. It is defined in terms of loads and stored from/to memory.

And the rules for atomicity regarding loads and stores are complex. They have to do with alignment and size of the stored value.

Your example of "call" does not make sense: It does not access memory. The concept of atomicity is unrelated to the call instruction.

Comment: No, what I was asking in case of "call" was, if it would be possible for the thread to be preempted before the called method starts execution. For example while resolving the reference.